# How to change an incorrect datetime format from a raw csv file to a proper datetime format in Python

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, python-datetime

I have a Python Dataframe like this

```
Index Name Dateofbirth

0      A.     12JAN1980:00:00:00.000000
1      B.   17JUN1954:00:00:00.000000
...
1250000  X.  09DEC1957:00:00:00.0000
```

The problem is that in the raw data csv file, my dates are stored in this format **%d%m%Y:00:00:00.000000**

So, the issue arises when I read this csv file into Python and convert Date of birth column into datetime with the following code

```
df['Dateofbirth'] =pd.to_datetime(df['Dateofbirth'])
```

I get the following error :

**raise ValueError("Unknown string format:", timestr) 
ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '12JAN1980:00:00:00.000000**

How can I change this format into the acceptable datetime format of %Y%m%d %H%M%S ? 
Changing the raw csv file is out of the question as there are over 1000000 rows.

Please help! I apologize for any lack of text formatting.

Comment: No it is stored with Date first, year end, but you are using `%Y%M%D`

Comment: But I'm not specifying anywhere that I need a Y first format. Either way is fine. How should I modify my code then?

Comment: Hi yes, you can specify the format, example: `pd.to_datetime('13000101', format='%Y%m%d', errors='ignore')`,

Comment: But now that entire column is an object instead of datetime64[ns]

Comment: I suppose that did not work. Because the entire column is still of a string type (object) instead of the required datetime64[ns]

Comment: `pd.to_datetime` work on string and convert datetime type, is that what you want

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think the main issue was because I kept writing %m when it should have been %b for the months.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it will return `Dateofbirth` with type object:

```
df['Dateofbirth'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Dateofbirth)
df['Dateofbirth'] = df['Dateofbirth'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d %H%M%S')
```

or using this if you want `Dateofbirth` as type datetime:

```
df['Dateofbirth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dateofbirth'])
df['Dateofbirth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dateofbirth'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d %H%M%S'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, also the issue was because I kept writing %m when it should have been %b for the months.

Comment: Oh yes, I didnt recognize that, sorry, your part say change into, but think you want to use data with that format and convert :D